# Ruby on Rail bitwise operators (&) for the complex types arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the bitwise operator (&) for the arrays in the Ruby on Rails

When I have the simple type arrays

```
one = ["one", "two", "three"]
two = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

And have this code

```
puts (one & two)
```

I get the output:

one two three

However, when I am having the complex types arrays

```
list1 = [Someitem.new("1", "item1"),Someitem.new("2", "item2"),Someitem.new("3", "item3"),Someitem.new("4", "item4")]
list2 = [Someitem.new("1", "item1"),Someitem.new("2", "item2"),Someitem.new("3", "item3"),Someitem.new("4", "item4")]
```

For the class where I do override the to_s method

```
class Someitem
    attr_accessor :item_id, :item_name
    def initialize(item_id, item_name)
      self.item_id = item_id;
      self.item_name= item_name;
    end
    
   def to_s
     item_name
   end  
end
```

And have this code

```
puts (list1 & list2)
```

I get nothing in the output

What can I do to get the output for the complex types arrays using the bitwise & operator to find common values within those two lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ruby 3.0 docs for [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#26-method) say:

> [...] items are compared using `eql?`

The Ruby 2.7 docs for [`Array#&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#26-method) say:

> It compares elements using their `hash` and `eql?` methods for efficiency

So in order to get this working for your class, you have to implement / override [`eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#eql-3F-method) and (for 2.7 compatibility) [`hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#hash-method) according to the docs. There are many ways to do this, here's a simple approach:

```
class Someitem

  # ...

  def hash
    [item_id, item_name].hash
  end

  def eql?(other)
    return false unless other.is_a?(Someitem)

    [item_id, item_name] == [other.item_id, other.item_name]
  end
  alias == eql?  # <- this isn't needed but convenient
end
```

The above implementation uses `item_id` and `item_name` to calculate the object's hash and to determine object equality:

```
Someitem.new("1", "item1").hash == Someitem.new("1", "item1").hash
#=> true

Someitem.new("1", "item1").eql? Someitem.new("1", "item1")
#=> true

[Someitem.new("1", "item1")] & [Someitem.new("1", "item1")]
#=> [#<Someitem:0x00007f8ff505d228 @item_id="1", @item_name="item1">]
```

Comment: Note that if the instance methods `eql?` and `hash` are not defined on the class `Someitem` the methods [Kernel#eql?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F) and [Kernel#hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-hash) apply. (`Someitem.instance_method(:eql?).owner #=> Kernel; Someitem.instance_method(:hash).owner #=> Kernel`.)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, while [Integer#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-26) is the bit-wise AND operator, [Array#&](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-26) is the *set intersection operator* (though I find the term "set" grating because an array is not a set).

You appear to be assuming that

```
Someitem.new("1", "item1") == Someitem.new("1", "item1") #=> true
```

However, the two instances are not the same object, so in fact:

```
Someitem.new("1", "item1") == Someitem.new("1", "item1") #=> false
```

Recalling that every object has a unique `object_id`, consider the following:

```
list1.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [1520, 1540, 1560, 1580]
list2.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [1600, 1620, 1640, 1660]
```

Since `[1520, 1540, 1560, 1580]` and `[1600, 1620, 1640, 1660]` have no common elements we see that their intersection is empty:

```
list1.map(&:object_id) & list2.map(&:object_id)
  #=> [1520, 1540, 1560, 1580] & [1600, 1620, 1640, 1660]
  #=> []
```

Answer (score 1):

When arrays are involved, `&` is actually the [intersection](http://t%20compares%20elements%20using%20their%20#hash%20and%20#eql?%20methods%20for%20efficiency.), it's not the `bitwise AND`.

To return the common elements between your lists, the `#hash` method is called.

For your first example, calling `"one".hash` returns the same value all the time, which is actually a hit.

```
"one".hash # => 103347303317675750
"one".hash # => 103347303317675750
```

In the second example you work with different instances, which, of course don't match.

```
Someitem.new("1", "item1").hash # => a_value
Someitem.new("1", "item1").hash # => another_value
```

If you pass the same instance to both arrays, it will match.

```
 a = Someitem.new("1", "item1")
 a.hash # => a_value
 a.hash # => same_value_as_above

 list1 = [a]
 list2 = [a]
 list1 & list2 # => [a]
```